# Champion Fighter's Remarkable Athlete and Hit Point Calculation

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, hit-points

The Champion Fighter's Remarkable Athlete ability states:

> add half your proficiency bonus (round up) to any Strength, Dexterity, or Constitution check you make that doesn't already use your proficiency bonus.(Pg. 72)

As we know, there are almost no constitution checks due to constitution lacking any relevant skills. The only thing we add Constitution too is our hp, in which:

> you add your Constitution modifier to each Hit Die you roll for your hit points.(pg. 177)

An ability check is:

> roll[ing] a d20 and add[ing] the relevant ability modifier. (pg 174)

So, would you add your proficiency bonus to your hit points as a Champion Fighter?

(Sorry if this seems really munchkin-y, I was just thinking about why it would say constitution checks when most const things are saving throws.)

Comment: Just because there are no skill proficiencies for Constitution doesn't mean there are almost no Constitution checks. Any time you are pushing yourself hard could conceivably have an interesting Con check.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  A hit point roll is not an ability check, per the rules you cited yourself in your question that define them differently.

Comment: Is this a case where getting d20 HD *would* make it a CON check, or would it still not be because the roll is usually not a d20?

Comment: They are different game constructs regardless of the size of the HD.

Comment: It might be worth adding examples of Constitution Ability Checks from the phb (or even other ones you may think of).

Comment: I think the question's been answered; I'm not a fan of just running on about everything I know that's related.